# Load file in browser window

Tags: php, yii, header, download

I have the following code in my Yii controller. When I enter the url for the controller (or click on a link with the controller URL), the document loads, but does not load inline (in other words, it prompts to download the file).

Otherwise normally a direct link to the file opens the file embedded in the browser window as desired, so I am able to do this normally.

How do I get the file to open in the browser window instead of forcing a download using the code below?

```
$filename = Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot') . '/docs/brochure.pdf';
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);

header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-length: '. strlen($contents));
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=your_brochure.pdf');

echo $contents;
```

Comment: Since you found your answer, you can write it up and accept it as the answer - [this is totally encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this. The culprit was this line

```
header('Content-Disposition: **attachment**; filename=your_brochure.pdf');
```

which I changed to

```
header('Content-Disposition: **inline**; filename=your_brochure.pdf')
```